# What is the c++ std library implementer's concern to warn the undefined behavior in adding specialization for remove_cvref template?

Tags: c++, c++20

In this link, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_cvref, it states

```
template< class T >
struct remove_cvref;
```

> If the type T is a reference type, provides the member typedef type which is the type referred to by T with its topmost cv-qualifiers removed. Otherwise type is T with its topmost cv-qualifiers removed.

> ***The behavior of a program that adds specializations for `remove_cvref` is undefined.***

What is the c++ std library implementer's concern in this case?

Comment: There is nothing special about `remove_cvref` in this regard. It is consistent with most of the standard library templated types which cannot be specialized by user. I don't understand your question or your motivation for your question.

Answer (score 6):

The C++ standard forbids specializations of pretty much any of the C++ type traits templates. The reason to do that is because the type traits are supposed to be low-level, basic constructs that do exactly and *only* what they say. This means that users should not be allowed to pull the usual shenanigans with them by replacing their functionality with whatever they want.

Let's say that you're in a template function over some template parameter type `T`. And you want to execute some code conditionally if `T` happens to be an `int`. But this code would work just fine if `T` is an `int&` or a `const int` or whatever. You just want to see if the user provided an `int` as a type.

You use `remove_cvref_t` to get `int` as a type, then `is_same_v` it against `int`. This can *only* work if `remove_cvref` does exactly and *only* what it says it does. If a user can specialize it, then they can lie to you, making their user-defined type appear like an `int` and thereby break your code.

Think of type-traits in C++ as language type operations that are defined in a header rather than always being present. By all rights, C++ ought to have an operator that converts a type into the removed-cvref version of itself. Instead of a dedicated operator, we have type trait metafunctions. But regardless of how it gets defined, it is still a fundamental operation that you should not be able to change the meaning of.